# How to draw samples from two correlated Negative Binomial variables?

Tags: self-study, correlation, copula

**Data and problem description:** my data is the number of corner kicks of home team, away team, total corner kicks and corner kicks difference. Below is code for data and the plots (assuming the number of corner kicks follows the Negative Binomial (NegBin) distribution.

```
### Data

epl_19_20 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/E0.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
epl_20_21 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2021/E0.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
epl_21_22 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2122/E0.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
epl_22_23 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/E0.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
epl_23_24 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2324/E0.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]

spa_19_20 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/SP1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
spa_20_21 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2021/SP1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
spa_21_22 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2122/SP1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
spa_22_23 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/SP1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
spa_23_24 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2324/SP1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]

ita_19_20 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/I1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
ita_20_21 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2021/I1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
ita_21_22 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2122/I1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
ita_22_23 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/I1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
ita_23_24 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2324/I1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]

ger_19_20 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/D1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
ger_20_21 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2021/D1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
ger_21_22 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2122/D1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
ger_22_23 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/D1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
ger_23_24 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2324/D1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]

fra_19_20 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/F1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
fra_20_21 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2021/F1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
fra_21_22 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2122/F1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
fra_22_23 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/F1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]
fra_23_24 = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2324/F1.csv')[, c('HC', 'AC')]

all_leagues = rbind(epl_19_20, epl_20_21, epl_21_22, epl_22_23, epl_23_24,
                    spa_19_20, spa_20_21, spa_21_22, spa_22_23, spa_23_24,
                    ita_19_20, ita_20_21, ita_21_22, ita_22_23, ita_23_24,
                    ger_19_20, ger_20_21, ger_21_22, ger_22_23, ger_23_24,
                    fra_19_20, fra_20_21, fra_21_22, fra_22_23, fra_23_24)

### Getting parameters for NegBin

hc_mu = mean(all_leagues$HC)
ac_mu = mean(all_leagues$AC)

hc_p = hc_mu / (var(all_leagues$HC))
ac_p = ac_mu / (var(all_leagues$AC))

hc_r = hc_mu**2 / (var(all_leagues$HC) - hc_mu)
ac_r = ac_mu**2 / (var(all_leagues$AC) - ac_mu)

hc_sim_pois = rpois(1e5, hc_mu)
ac_sim_pois = rpois(1e5, ac_mu)

hc_sim_negbin = rnbinom(1e5, size = hc_r, prob = hc_p)
ac_sim_negbin = rnbinom(1e5, size = ac_r, prob = ac_p)

### Plots

plot(prop.table(table(all_leagues$HC)), type = 'l', col = 'red', ylim = c(0, 0.17),
     xlab = 'Home corner kicks', ylab = 'Probability')
lines(prop.table(table(hc_sim_negbin)), type = 'l', col = 'green')
legend(10, 0.11, legend=c("Actual", "NegBin"),
       col=c("red", 'green'), lty = 1)

plot(prop.table(table(all_leagues$AC)), type = 'l', col = 'red', ylim = c(0, 0.19),
     xlab = 'Away corner kicks', ylab = 'Probability')
lines(prop.table(table(ac_sim_negbin)), type = 'l', col = 'green')
legend(15, 0.11, legend=c("Actual", "NegBin"),
       col=c("red", 'green'), lty = 1)

plot(prop.table(table(all_leagues$HC + all_leagues$AC)), type = 'l', col = 'red', ylim = c(0, 0.16),
     xlab = 'Total corner kicks', ylab = 'Probability')
lines(prop.table(table(round(hc_sim_negbin) + round(ac_sim_negbin))), type = 'l', col = 'green')
legend(16, 0.11, legend=c("Actual", "NegBin"),
       col=c("red", 'green'), lty = 1)

plot(prop.table(table(all_leagues$HC - all_leagues$AC)), type = 'l', col = 'red', ylim = c(0, 0.16),
     xlab = 'Corner kicks difference', ylab = 'Probability')
lines(prop.table(table(hc_sim_negbin - ac_sim_negbin)), type = 'l', col = 'green')
legend(10, 0.11, legend=c("Actual", "NegBin"),
       col=c("red", 'green'), lty = 1)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Assumption (could be either right or wrong):**

- The number of corner kicks follows the NegBin distribution and there is a dependence between home and away.

**My ideas and what I tried:**

- Using copula (which I don't know how to implement)
- Call X, Y, Z are three NegBin variables then (X + Z) represents for the home corner kicks and (Y + Z) represents for the away corner kicks. In this case, I have 6 parameters (2 for each variable)

For example, if I set the 6 parameters in this way, my plots would look like this (there's a slight improvement but 6 parameters are quite a lot to tune).

```
params = c(5.054445, 7.178582, 4.669547, 5.728449, 0.586997, 3.549629)
X_mu = params[1]
X_var = params[2]
X_p = X_mu / X_var
X_r = X_mu**2 / (X_var - X_mu)

Y_mu = params[3]
Y_var = params[4]
Y_p = Y_mu / Y_var
Y_r = Y_mu**2 / (Y_var - Y_mu)

Z_mu = params[5]
Z_var = params[6]
Z_p = Z_mu / Z_var
Z_r = Z_mu**2 / (Z_var - Z_mu)
Z = rnbinom(1e5, size = Z_r, prob = Z_p)

XZ_sim = rnbinom(1e5, size = X_r, prob = X_p) + Z
YZ_sim = rnbinom(1e5, size = Y_r, prob = Y_p) + Z
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**My questions:**

How to draw samples from two correlated Negative Binomial variables?

Thank you.